# How to fetch a list of nodes by content type in a Rules Action set?

Tags: rules

I am trying to create a [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) Component that fetches a list of nodes based on their content type. But when I try creating it, I get a little stuck. Here's my process:

1. I create a rules component using "action component"
2. Then add an action to the component "fetch entity by property"
3. Select the entity type I would like to fetch "node"

I am then presented with the following:

[image: fetch entity by type]

In the value box I don't have node types nor a way to pass a text string that represents one, I have tried several ways by including introducing a text variable set to the entity type but if I try and use that as the value I get an error which says something about the variable being the wrong type.

Comment: I don't have access to the sire anymore as the question was asked three years ago, sorry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce a variable of type **Text Token** with the content type as the value.

```
Parameter: Type: Text token, Value: content_type
```

And then use this new variable as the value for comparison with the property.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this Rules Component (an Action Set), in Rules export format:

```
{ "rules_fetch_all_nodes_of_a_selected_content_type" : {
    "LABEL" : "Fetch all nodes of a selected content type",
    "PLUGIN" : "action set",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : { "fetched_content_type" : { "label" : "Fetched content type", "type" : "token" } },
    "ACTION SET" : [
      { "entity_query" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "node",
            "property" : "type",
            "value" : [ "fetched-content-type" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_fetched" : { "node_fetched" : "Fetched node" } }
        }
      },
      { "LOOP" : {
          "USING" : { "list" : [ "node-fetched" ] },
          "ITEM" : { "current_node" : "Current node" },
          "DO" : [
            { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Title of current node  (with nid = [current-node:nid]) is [current-node:title]" } }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After you import it in your own site, use the "execute" link (to the right of it) to experiment with it in your own site.

As a sample, enter a value like `article` for its input parameter (=`fetched_content_type`, which is the machine name of the content type to be processed). After you do, it'll show a Drupal message for each of your nodes with a content type that matches the value of your parameter. Here is a sample of such messages:

```
Title of current node (with nid = 19) is How to do X?
Title of current node (with nid = 53) is Hello World ...
Title of current node (with nid = 57) is Bonjour!
```